# invariant subspace problem query

Tags: functional-analysis

I have a few questions on the invariant subspace problem

1) Why do they insist on invariant subpaces being closed.

2) The question only asks about banach or hilbert spaces. What is an example of a infinite dimensional complex vector space with no invariant subspace ?

Thanks

Comment: Who are "they"?

Comment: I mean the question asks about closed invariant subpaces. Is their somethng special about closed?

Comment: And what is "the question"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Because "they" want the subspace to be a vector space by itself.

Without this requirement it is very easy to construct invariant subspaces, as standard vector spaces bases are too big.

2) As vector spaces any operator on a complex vector space (of dimension at least 2) has an invariant subspace. The proof is simple:

If $V$ is finite dimensional, then the operator has an eigenvalue, and you take an eigenvector.

If it is infinite dimensional, pick a vector $u$ and look at

$$Span \{ T(u), T^2(u),... \}$$

If this is not $V$, it is an invariant subspace, and if this is $V$ it means you can write $u$ as a finite linear combination of vectors in here. Then, that finite linear combination gives you a finite invariant subspace.

The answer to both of your questions is: we don't care because the answer is known and very simple..

Comment: Thanks for your response. What would the 'finite invariant subspace' be exactly. Also, a banach space is a vector space so why doesn't this argument work for them?

Comment: @user108605  If $u= \sum_{k=1}^n a_k T^k(u)$ with $a_n \neq 0$, then you can write $T^n(u)=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} b_k T^k(u)$ and then $T^n(u) \in Span\{ u, T(u),..., T^{n-1}(u) \}$. From here it is easy to prove that $ Span\{ u, T(u),..., T^{n-1}(u) \}$ is invariant...

Comment: @user108605 And in Banach spaces, closure allows us take infinite sums... And that makes the problem much harder. If you look to the proof, I used the fact that the proof ends at $T^n(u)$, if the sum is a series, my argument doesn't work anymore... In general, $Span \{ T(u), T^2(u),... \} \neq V$ but is dense in $V$. That's why the closure makes a difference.

Comment: can you give an example of a complex metric space with no closed invariant subspace?