# representation theory and schur's lemma

Tags: representation-theory

I was doing the exercises in serre's book on representation theory in p.26:

Show directly , using Schur's lemma, that irreducible representation of an abelian group, finite or infinite, has degree 1.

But I cant solve it, could someone please help?

Comment: Could you show us what you've tried to do?

Answer (score 3):

The statement is wrong, even in the case of finite groups and finite vector spaces. Consider the rotation by 90 degrees in the real plane. It is a real, irreducible but two-dimensional representation of $C_4$. There is obviously some assumption about the field being algebraically closed missing here.

But even then it is still wrong. Consider $K(x)$ as a $K$-vectorspace and let $G=K(x)^\times$ be the multiplicative group acting by multiplication in the field. This is an irreducible representation, but of infinite dimension. The same works if $G\leq L^\times$ for some proper field extension $K\subseteq L$ and $G$ spans $L$ as a $K$-vectorspace (which includes the above example by the way: $G=\{\pm1,\pm i\}\leq\mathbb{C}^\times$ spans $\mathbb{C}$ as an $\mathbb{R}$-vectorspace).

In fact every counterexample is more or less of this form: If $\omega:G\to GL(V)$ is irreducible and $V$ is a vectorspace over some field $K$, then Schur's Lemma tells you, that the centralizer of $\omega(G)\leq GL(V)$ is a skew field extension $K\subseteq D$.

If $G$ is abelian, then $\omega(G)$ lies in its own centralizer. If $D=K$ (in which case $V$ is called *absolutely* irreducible and that's certainly what the exercise had in mind), this means that all $\omega(g)$ are scalar multiples of the identity which immediatly implies $\dim_K(V)=1$.

But if $D$ is bigger than $K$, then $\omega(G)\leq D^\times$ generates a field extension $K\subseteq L\subseteq D$. Then we can view $V$ as an $L$-vectorspace and $G$ acts by $L$-scalar multiples of the identity. Hence $\dim_L(V)=1$. If $G$ would not span $L$ as an $K$-vectorspace then the $K$-span of the $G$-orbit of any non-zero vector in $V$ would be a proper submodule contradicting the simplicity of $V$.

To summarize: There are counterexamples and they all given by subgroups $G\leq L^\times$ that span $L$ as a $K$-vectorspace and act on $L$ by multiplication.

---

Now if $V$ is *finite dimensional* and $K$ is *algebraically closed*, then every $\omega(g)$ has at least one eigenvector and commutativity implies that there exists a simultaneous eigenvector which spans a one-dimensional submodule. By simplicity $\dim_K(V)=1$.

Comment: So $V$ is assumed to be finite-dimensional. That answers that. ;-)

Comment: how does "commutativity [imply] that there exists a simultaneous eigenvector"? The best I can get is that if $AB = BA$ then for an eigenvectors $u| Au = u$ that $Bu$ is necessarily an eigenvector, (and by symmetry you can similarly find eigenvectors of $B$), but it's not clear why these are shared.

Comment: That's standard exercise and you have already solved it halfway: If $AB=BA$, then $B$ maps every $A$-eigenspace $Eig_\lambda(A)$ into itself (and $A$ maps every $B$-eigenspace $Eig_\mu(B)$ into itself). Now choose an eigenvector $v\in Eig_\lambda(A)$ for the restricted operator $B_{|Eig_\lambda(A)}$ and you're done. In fact, this easily generalizes to families of commuting matrices of arbitrary size by induction and implies many neat little gems like the fact that every commutative subalgebra of $K^{n\times n}$ is conjugated a subalgebra consisting of upper triangular matrices.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Let $\phi: G \to GL(V)$ be an irreducible representation, $G$ abelian. Show that there exists $v \in V$ a common eigenvector for all $\phi(g)$.

Note that this approach requires the assumption that $V$ is finite-dimensional, but not that $G$ is finite. As Johannes Hahn's answer shows, the proposition is false if $V$ is allowed to be infinite-dimensional.

Comment: This works for finite, but not for infinite groups. Consider for example $V:=\bigoplus_{k\in\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{C}$ and the (infinite cyclic group generated by the) shift operator $V\to V$.

Comment: I was typing that up at the same time as you, lol! I suppose you need to prove every infinite-dimensional representation has a proper subrepresentation? Or maybe Serre intended the assumption that the vector spaces be finite dimensional to hold implicitly, as it does for most of the book.

Comment: maybe the group can be infinite but the representations are considered finite-dimensional

Comment: I kinda doubt that (though that is what I proposed above), but I don't know how to solve the infinite-dimensional case. I did find [this proof](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/659469/invariant-subspace-problem-query) that any operator on an infinite-dimensional vector space has a proper invariant subspace, but it doesn't apply here, because we also need an invariant subspace for the inverse operator, and one which is simultaneous across all elements of the group. Maybe the proof can be adapted.

Comment: To be clear: this approach works just fine as long as $V$ is finite-dimensional, even if $G$ is infinite.